# Centroid Value Changing

Tags: python

```
from math import dist
def distance(pos1,pos2): 
    return dist(pos1,pos2)

def find_closest(location, centroids):
    dista=centroids
    start=0
    for i in range(len(centroids)):
        dista[start]=distance(location, centroids[start])
        start+=1
    end=0
    for i in range(len(centroids)):
        if min(dista)==dista[end]:
            break
        end+=1
    return centroids[end]
```

This function will loop over a list called centroids and find the closest one to a specific location. However my list centroids is changing along with our new list dista. PS I want to return the centroid not the distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dista=centroids

That means you’re declaring a new name to the list, not a new list, you should make a new list,try for loop

```
dista=[]
for i in centroids:
    dista.append(i)
```

To prevent falling in the same mistake again, understand how vars work

```
Echo=print
Echo(“hello”)
#output : hello
```